# Email doesn't contain first few lines got by output buffer php

Tags: php, ob-start

I have a php script containing a function which when run gives output. I am using that output as output buffer by using ob_start and ob_get_clean functions and emailing that output which contains some html as a report. Problem is, email doesn't first few lines of output, tried many times but every time first few lines are missing.

How to resolve this?

```
<?php
function abc{
echo 'Server Time: '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').'<br>';
echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>
Vestibulum semper purus ut felis interdum at tempus turpis imperdiet. <br> 
Donec varius accumsan magna nec blandit. <br>
Donec a pellentesque ligula. Curabitur accumsan mauris non velit vehicula sodales. <br>
Phasellus vestibulum vestibulum nunc ut lobortis. Ut eu rutrum orci. Phasellus tempor eleifend congue. <br>
In mollis porta arcu. Integer congue fringilla lorem.";
}

function mailasreport($message) {
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
mail('example@hotmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
}
ob_start();
abc();
$report = ob_get_clean();
mailasreport($report);
?>
```

Email Output:

```
Donec varius accumsan magna nec blandit.
Donec a pellentesque ligula. Curabitur accumsan mauris non velit vehicula sodales. 
Phasellus vestibulum vestibulum nunc ut lobortis. Ut eu rutrum orci. Phasellus tempor eleifend congue. 
In mollis porta arcu. Integer congue fringilla lorem.
```

Original Code is very long, this is its small clone!

Comment: Do you have some example code?

Comment: @Patrick, wait adding code

Comment: You know there is a syntax error in your code, right? You are missing a quote in the mail function. You also call the function `acb`, while it's called `abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `ob_get_contents();` also?

```
ob_start();
//do your stuff
...
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

### Edit:

Example test script, test this and see, note you should always validate user input else you could be a spam host in the future, the example has no validation.

```
<?php
function makeMail(){
    return '
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Time: '.date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A").'</h1>
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum semper purus ut felis interdum at tempus turpis imperdiet.</li>
    <li>Donec varius accumsan magna nec blandit.</li>
</ol>
<h3 style="color:red;">
            Donec a pellentesque ligula. Curabitur accumsan mauris non velit vehicula sodales.<br />
            Phasellus vestibulum vestibulum nunc ut lobortis. Ut eu rutrum orci. Phasellus tempor eleifend congue.<br />
            In mollis porta arcu. Integer congue fringilla lorem.</h3>
<p>yada ;p</p>
</body>
</html>';
}

/**
 * Send email
 */
function sendMail($to, $from, $subject, $content){
    $headers ='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8'."\r\n";
    $headers.='From:<'.$from.'>'."\r\n";
    $headers.="X-Mailer: PHP"."\r\n";
    return @mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers) ? true : false;
}

ob_start();
//do your stuff
echo makeMail();
$email_contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if(sendMail('to@example.com', 'from@examlpe.com', 'Email Subject', $email_contents)){
    //sent
    echo 'sent';
}else{
    //fail
    echo 'fail';
}
?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: offtopic ... could you tell me how to write profile name like yours ? that is awesome

Comment: @NullPointer by using the utf8 Spacing modifier letters,  N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞ7ę̴̽̓ͯ̿̃̈͊ͨͥ̒̀͏͓͈̟͇̻̯̦̟̝̳̟̩̘̩͉̯͇͈̖r̷͕̜̘̗̀ͨ̏͌̚̚l‌​̭̹͖̺͈̞̖̩̰̱͇̖͗ͫ͐̇ͦ́̎̒ͪ̾ͫ̃̏ͮ̓̀͝

Comment: @user2299278, you are not using `ob_get_contents()` as lawrence suggested. What are your results when you use that function?

Comment: just tested this with what you said, it gave same results!!

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè above is exactly what I'm using!

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè  this is working fine, without missing anything!

Comment: Make sure you have a doctype on the email, just as if it is a valid html page, tho prob not the problem, it might be the shortcut ob_get_clean() function. not 100% lol could be anything really, also dont forget the parenthesis on function `mailasreport()` and the concatenating of `$headers` before it set, tho prob a typo

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè , I worked your way but its not working as intended, it is still missing those lines